# How does export_fig compare to the new exportgraphics function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pdf, export-to-pdf

When saving plots to PDF in MATLAB one had to use a tool like [export_fig](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/) in order to prevent that the PDF looks totally different from the plot on the screen.

`export_fig` added a hint to use `exportgraphics` from MATLAB in a [commit in 2020](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/commit/8b0ba1314514d2ff47cef4b8d4701605e42e6312)

What should a user keep in mind when deciding whether to use the internal `exportgraphics` or the external `export_fig` tool with MATLAB 2022a or later?

What are the major differences?

Comment: I don't know about `export_fig`, but I personally only use `exportgraphics`, which works very well, using [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/861570-exportgraphics-adding-a-margin) to have the PDF look the same than the figure